# Algebra deduction?

Tags: algebra

I was trying to use Mathematica for some simple algebra deduction, but it didnt work. code:

```
TrueQ@(Sqrt[(e0 u0)/(e1 u1)] == Sqrt[e0 u0]/Sqrt[e1 u1])
```

Any ideas how to make Mathematica know these equations are the same?

Comment: `TrueQ` is not usually used this way.  Suppose you have a condition (e.g., `A == B` as in your case). There are three possibilities: it computes to `True`, it computes to `False`, and its value cannot be computed. The function `If[]` for instance does different things in each case. `TrueQ` is used to force the last case to be `False`. It is used for programming and not for mathematics. If you have a procedure that should not be executed unless it is known that the condition is true, then `TrueQ` is convenient to combine the `False` and the undecided cases together.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assume `e1,u1` are positive

```
Assuming[e1 > 0 && u1 > 0, Simplify[Sqrt[(e0 u0)/(e1 u1)] - Sqrt[e0 u0]/Sqrt[e1 u1]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Let look and see why. Consider the simple example

```
Clear[x]
expr = Sqrt[1/x] - 1/Sqrt[x];
Simplify[expr]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If `x` is negative, then `Sqrt[1/x]` is `Sqrt[-1/Abs[x]]` which is `I*Sqrt[1/Abs[x]]` which is not the same as `1/Sqrt[x]`. But if `x>0` then `Sqrt[1/x]=1/Sqrt[x]`

```
Assuming[x > 0, Simplify[expr]]
(* 0 *)
```

And that is what happened in your expression.

Comment: But if I try Assuming[e1 > 0 && u1 > 0, TrueQ[Sqrt[(e0 u0)/(e1 u1)] == Sqrt[e0 u0]/Sqrt[e1 u1]]] it still gives `False`

Comment: Yep, changed to Simplify and it worked. Thanks

Comment: Also, I think `TrueQ` is really meant for structural sameness. Not Math-wise sameness.  i.e. when both sides are exactly the same structurally. Any way, I normally just use Simplify when Assuming.

Comment: For example,  `TrueQ[Exp[I x] == Cos[x] + I*Sin[x]]` gives `False` but `Simplify[Exp[I x] == Cos[x] + I*Sin[x]]` gives `True`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/86288)

Comment: @[Nasser](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/70/nasser). The definition of [TrueQ](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrueQ.html) is that way. For Your intent use: `TrueQ[ExpToTrig@Exp[I x] == Cos[x] + I*Sin[x]]` or vice versa. The Attributes of TrueQ is [Protected](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Protected.html). `Protected` is an attribute that prevents any values associated with a symbol from being modified.